# PHP deleting a single item in shopping cart using form with value of $i

Tags: php, session, unset

I have a simple shopping cart project I'm working on, where I pull information out of my database. One component of this shopping cart is the ability to delete a single item. For the most part it works. What I can't figure out is this bug regarding the index. Here is my code. I'll explain the problem thereafter.

```
$cartoutput = "";
$cartTotal="";

if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
    $cartoutput = "<div align='center'><font style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 20pt;'>Your order is currently empty.</font></div>";
}else{
    $i=1;

    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
            if (!$result) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));// Displays the error that mysql will generate if syntax is not correct.
            exit();
            }


            //echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $id = $row['id'];       
                $product_name = $row["name"];
                $price = $row["price"]; 
                $description = $row['description'];             
        }


            $cartoutput .= " <tr><td width='20%'> Order Item $i </td> 
                            <td width='40%'>  " . $product_name . "</td>
                            <td width='20%'> $" . $price . ".00</td>";

            $cartoutput .=" <td width='20%'><form action='cart.php' method='post'>
                            <input name='deleteBtn" . $item_id . "'type='submit' value='Remove This Item' />
                            <input name='index_to_remove' type='hidden' value='" . $i . "' />   
                            </form></td></tr>";
            $i++;



    }
}
```

The area of attention is the $cartoutput where I use a form to delete an item. The value I use is `$i` and for the most part it works. This is the code that processes that form:

```
if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        header("location: cart.php");
        } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        //sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
```

The problem i'm having is when I have 3 or more items. If `$i=3` in my shopping cart, and a user deletes the second item (`$i=2`) it's deleted. Then `$i=3` becomes `$i=2`, and if you try to delete $i=2 again (or the second item again) my code doesn't work as it doesn't delete the new index that replaces the item that was deleted.

I've tried nearly everything. I've changed forms, tried unsetting different parameters. Nothing is working. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this bug? I'll select the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Check my answer update below

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Numeric arrays are 0-base indexed

**2-** After item delete, re-order your array. Example :

```
unset($_SESSION["cart_array"][$key_to_remove]);
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array_values($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
```

**UPDATE**

You could also use this syntax and no need to re-order your cart array.

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $i => $each_item) { 
    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));// Displays the error that mysql will generate if syntax is not correct.
        exit();
        }


        //echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $id = $row['id'];       
            $product_name = $row["name"];
            $price = $row["price"]; 
            $description = $row['description'];             
    }


        $cartoutput .= " <tr><td width='20%'> Order Item $i </td> 
                        <td width='40%'>  " . $product_name . "</td>
                        <td width='20%'> $" . $price . ".00</td>";

        $cartoutput .= " <td width='20%'><form action='cart.php' method='post'>
                        <input name='deleteBtn" . $item_id . "'type='submit' value='Remove This Item' />
                        <input name='index_to_remove' type='hidden' value='" . $i . "' />   
                        </form></td></tr>";

}
```

`$i` will be the item index in each iteration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: that didn't work, sorry. I can delete the second item, and then the third items becomes the new second item, but when I hit the delete button again (on the new second item) it doesn't actually get deleted. Just as it was before.

Comment: Did you refresh the page after delete?

Comment: I just tried it with refreshing the page, and it still does not work. Not sure where to go from here.